# Rails bootstrap datepicker - Calendar is covered by drop down list when adding new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-datepicker

I have some strange behavior happening with bootstrap datepicker in a rails form. I'm using form_for in a partial for edit and new. When editing, the calendar shows perfectly when clicking on the date field but when adding a new record, the calendar is covered over by a dropdown list containing about 6 dates recently entered via the form. The calendar control is also open under the list. I can see the right edge of it. Also, when I move the browser window around or go to another open app and then back to the browser, only the calendar is there...the drop down list disappears.  So odd!

I've been searching for a solution for several weeks and have scoured the internet and the datepicker documentation but just can't figure this out.  Any guidance appreciated!

Here is the text_field within my form_for.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_field :visit_date, {"data-provide" => 'datepicker', 
"data-date-format" => "yyyy-mm-dd", "data-date-autoclose" => 
"true"} %>
 <%= f.text_area :location, placeholder: "Add visit location..." %>
</div>
```

I have the gem in my gem file as:

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.8.0'
```

I have the following in my application.js file:

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

And I have this in my application.css.scss file:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of alternatif solution for your problem is to turned off autocomplete field, you can turned off html autocomplete from previous input with this command below

```
<%= form_for @your_data , :html => {:autocomplete=> 'off'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Wow!  What a simple solution.  That worked.  Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!